Why element of coordinate vector cannot be $0$?
Let $B=\{\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n\}$ be an ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, $S=\mathrm{span}\{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{v}_3\}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $3$, and $T=\{A\mathbf{x}:\mathbf{x}\in S\}$, where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.
If $S=T$, I was able to show that
$$(A\mathbf{v}_3)_B=(c_1,c_2,c_3,0,\ldots,0),$$
where $c_1,c_2,c_3\in\mathbb{R}$.
I cannot see why $c_3\ne0$. This might be very simple but I have been thinking about this for a week and I can not see why $c_3\ne0$. Could someone please help?

Why do you think that $c_3$ has to be different from $0$?

It's both possible that $c_3\neq 0$ (consider $A=I$) and that $c_3=0$ (consider the transposition matrix swapping $v_2$ and $v_3$).

That is my question. Why $c_3\ne0$? This was stated by my professor but I can not see it no matter how hard I tried for a week to think about this.

@Lucy $c_3\neq 0$ is not necessarily true. If we have a matrix that swaps $v_2$ and $v_3$, then $S=T$ and $(Av_3)_B=(0,1,0,0,...,0)$. Maybe you're missing another condition on A (like diagonalisability)?

@Tom The only other information is that $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and has dimension $3$. Does this imply that $c_3\ne0$. I will add this to my question.

The only thing you know for sure is that $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$ cannot all be zero at the same time for $Av_i$

@Lucy if those are your only conditions, then no.

@whpowell96 Could you please explain why?

Of course $c_3$ can be zero.
We don't know.   There's not enough information to know.
It's just that not all three of $c_1,c_2, c_3$ can be zero.
Because then $Av_3=\vec0,$ which is ruled out.

$v_3\in S$ so $Av_3\in T$ and since $S=T$, then $Av_3\in S$ so there are $c_1,c_2,c_3\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $Av_3=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3$. Since $Av_3\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $B$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, there are $d_1,\ldots,d_n$ such that $Av_3=d_1v_1+\cdots+d_nv_n$ so $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3=d_1v_1+\cdots+d_nv_n$. So using that $B$ is a basis, we have $d_1=c_1$, $d_2=c_2$, $d_3=c_3$ and $d_4=\ldots=d_n=0$. So $Av_3=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3+0v_4+\cdots+0v_n$ and then $(Av_3)_B=(c_1,c_2,c_3,0,\ldots,0)$.

Yes $Av_3$ is in the span of ${v_1,v_2,v_3}.$  But  $Av_3$ is necessarily only one dimensional.   By rank-nullity,  its dimension can't exceed $1.$  You're dropping the restrictions on $c_1, c_2, c_3,$ without  it being warranted.  You simply have that $\exists c_1, c_2, c_3$ such that $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3=Av_3.$  You seem to be substituting the quantifier $\forall $ in place of $\exists. $

Actually,  let me correct myself.   $Av_3$ is just a single vector.  So not even a vector space.   But since it's non-zero, its span is $1$dimensional.
